# different views in windows 7 phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7, view, frames

I am new to Windows Phone 7 application development. Can we create different views in same page, like a Web Application , in a Windows Phone 7 application?

in Web application in one page we have showing different view like (Example: registration in one view and Registrion View in another View but both views are in same page (Regiatrationpage.aspx) like that can we create views or frames in windows 7 phone application

If so kindly guide me

Comment: ok:- Please clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each page in a WP7 application can be constructed in any way that you see fit. However, you should take a look at the [Windows Phone 7 Series UI Design & Interaction Guide](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/03/18/windows-phone-7-series-ui-design-amp-interaction-guide.aspx) for inspiration, information about the Metro design language, and the way in what applications should be put together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a web app hosted in a windows 7 app although I'm not sure why you'd want to.